# ASP.NET Web Forms Maximize forms as screen size

Tags: c#, asp.net, vertical-alignment, maximize

I am new to ASP.NET designing. I have 2 pages "`Default`" & "`LoggedMaster`". I am facing problem in showing the screen in center & maximized - using all the space available.

`Default.aspx` just has a `<asp:Login>` in `<div>` in `<form>` in it. I could make the div utilize full Width & show the Login on center horizontal wise. But couldn't make it centerize vertically also. Here's the code of Default.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormApplication._Default" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
    <title>Trial N Error</title>

 </head>

<body bgcolor="#0099ff">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; width: 100%; ">
<div align="center" 
    style="background-color: #00FFFF; background-repeat: inherit; height: 100%; width: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" >

    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" 
        BorderPadding="10" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
        Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#333333" >
        <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="Medium" />
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Medium" 
            ForeColor="#284775" />
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" 
            ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Login>

    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" 
        NavigateUrl="~/LoggedHomeForm.aspx" BorderStyle="None">Master Page</asp:HyperLink>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `LoggedMaster.aspx` : This is a master page with 2 `ContentPlaceHolder`'s. Again here, horizontally it's occuping full space. But vertically, it's taking just space as much added in the content. I want it to occupy all the space though the content might be less. Also the menu, how can I make it use all the horizontal space as much as it has. Here's the code :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoggedMaster.master.cs" Inherits="WebFormApplication.LoggedMaster" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>

 </head>

 <body bgcolor="#33ccff">
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%" width="100%" >
<table bgcolor="#999966" style="height: 100%" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" height="48">
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#999966" 
                DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Large" 
                ForeColor="#666666" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
                <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
                <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" />
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/LoggedHomeForm.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="PFA" Value="PFA"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="PUC" Value="PUC"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Client" Value="Client"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Channel" Value="Channel"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/AboutForm.aspx" Text="About" Value="About">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" >
           <div id="headDiv" align="center" 
                style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px; width: 100%; clip: rect(auto, auto, 10px, auto)">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >

           </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </td>


    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" height="48" style="font-size: medium; font-weight: bold">
            Copyright 2015 Terry Consulting</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

The contentpage, currently just has a label for both the placeholders. But their will be forms with many fields & so. I searched on net for the same and also tried different ways, but nothing works well for me.

I think there is just some minor thing that either I am missing out or not setting appropriately. Can you please help me find out and resolve the problems.

Any help is highly appreciated.